# Swapping two files in shell

Tags: shell

I'm trying to switch the contents of two files via temp file using the code;

```
#!/bin/bash

...

mv $FILE1 $TEMP
mv $FILE2 $FILE1
mv $TEMP $FILE2
```

When I run this, it returns for each line number

> swap.sh: line 18: mv: command not found

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not running this script from `cron`, are you? Cron does not set any PATH so you have to set it in the script, preferably with `PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you are unsetting PATH variable with shell parameters.

Try adding full paths to commands, for example

```
/bin/mv ...
```

Using command which you can figure out what is correct path:

```
which mv
```

Alternatively you can try setting PATH at the beginning of script, for example:

> PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin

This is system dependent. You can see the default PATH by running

```
echo $PATH
```

in your shell.

Comment: A system's "default" PATH is better investigated with `/usr/bin/getconf PATH`. Everything else may give you more or less a random list of directories :-)

Answer (score 0):

The POSIXy way to initialize your scripts with a proper PATH is

```
PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)
```

Put this before the first command invokation and you should be set **and** protected from surprises by some random dude who has setup the shell profiles with his idea of what a PATH should look like.

You may wish to augment this, **if** you need programs from other directories, e.g.

```
PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH):/usr/local/bin
```